# FindRoot Accuracy

Tags: equation-solving

How can I get `FindRoot` to be more accurate?  I would require a solution for `r` that leaves `expr` at least much closer to zero.  (I can check `expr` to some tolerance and discard the result if it's too far out.)

```
expr = 34334.9 (1 + r) - 150000 (1 + r)^0.16129 + 145472 (1 + r)^0.0645161 - 15177.4;

Clear[r]

r = r /. FindRoot[expr == 0, {r, -0.75}]

expr
```

> 6142.92

```
Plot[expr, {r, -1, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: From the plot it seems `expr` has no roots. `NMinimize` perhaps?

Comment: 'No solution' would be ok.  I am just surprised at the approximate answer, and wondering if I can control the accuracy, rather than have to check the result.

Comment: I see. Did you check for the usual options `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal`, etc? What happens if you `Rationalize` your floats?

Comment: I tried `AccuracyGoal`.  I don't think it improved much a fairly accurate minimum.  Maybe it's just simplest to check the value of `expr`.

Comment: BTW if I execute your code, I do get an error message "...unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function." This means that something went wrong and, in this case, means the function has no roots. So this is basically your "no solution" message.

Comment: I think that can also happen for results that I would consider good, but I'll check.

Comment: You do get a “FindRoot::lstol” message indicating FindRoot[] thinks it probably failed. — I assume you know the limits on accuracy, $\Delta x \approx x\,10^{-wp}$ and $\Delta f \ approx f’(x) \, \Delta x$. Normally FindRoot[] is pretty aggressive at making $f(x)$ as small as possible. At some point though you can improve accuracy only by increasing working precision $wp$. —Aha! Try FindRoot[expr, {r, -1, -0.5}]

Comment: Yes, it looks like I can use the message response as a check, e.g. `r = Quiet[Check[r /. FindRoot[expr == 0, {r, -0.75}], "no solution", FindRoot::lstol]]]`

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear[r]

expr = 
  34334.9 (1 + r) - 150000 (1 + r)^0.16129 + 145472 (1 + r)^0.0645161 - 
   15177.4;

Minimize[expr // Rationalize[#, 0] &, r]

(* {-(75887/5), {r -> -1}} *)
```

Since the minimum is negative there must be a root.

```
prec = 30;

sol = FindRoot[SetPrecision[expr, prec] == 0, {r, -1}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> prec]

(* {r -> -0.99999999999999890965199354718} *)
```

Verifying the solution

```
SetPrecision[expr, prec] /. sol

(* 0.*10^-12 *)

Plot[SetPrecision[expr, prec], {r, -1.0005, -0.999}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> prec]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For non-extreme solutions this is the type of routine I came up with.

```
froot[expr_, guess_] := Module[{a, check = Null},
  Quiet[
   a = r /. FindRoot[expr == 0, {r, guess}, MaxIterations -> 1000];
   If[Length[$MessageList] > 0, check = ToString[$MessageList]]];

  If[StringQ[check], Print[check]];
  If[Head[a] === Complex, Print["Complex"]];

  If[Or[StringQ[check], Head[a] === Complex], "No solution", a]]

Clear[r]

expr = 34334.9 (1 + r) - 150000 (1 + r)^0.16129 + 145472 (1 + r)^0.0645161 - 15177.4;
guess = -0.75;
froot[expr, guess]
```

> {FindRoot::lstol}
>
> No solution