# Error message from FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

I am getting the following message when I evaluate a call to `FindRoot`:

> The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

What action should I take to eliminate the problem? the answer given by `FindRoot` is not correct, and `NSolve` dosen't work.

code:

```
ClearAll
ρ = 1000;
Rs = 1233;
η = 1/1000;
Cs = 2111;
Rc = 100*10^-6;
Rb = 20*10^-6;
Δ = (2*η/ρ ω)^(1/2);
c = 1500;
ζb = (Δ/Rb);
ζc = Δ/Rc;
k = (ω/c) (1 - I ω (4 η/3))^-(1/2);
ks = ω/Cs;
μ = (74/100)*10^9;
λ = Cs^2*Rs - 2 μ;
a12 = (1 + 2 ζb^2 (I - k Rb)) Exp[-I k Rb];
a13 = 0;
a21 = (I k Rc - 1) Exp[I k Rc];
a22 = -(I k Rc + 1) Exp[-I k Rc];
a23 = (I ω ) Exp[(I ks Rc)] (I ks Rc - 1);
a31 = I ρ ω Rc^-1 (1 + 2 ζc^2 (I + k Rc)) Exp[(I k Rc)];
a32 = I ρ ω Rc^-1 (1 + 2 ζc^2 (I - k Rc)) Exp[(-I k Rc)];
a33 = -Rc^-3 ((λ + 2 μ) (ks Rc)^2 + 4 μ (I  ks  Rc - 1)) Exp[(I  ks Rc)];
a11 = (1 + 2 ζb^2 (I + k Rb)) Exp[I k Rb];
a = Det[{{a11, a12, a13}, {a21, a22, a23}, {a31, a32, a33}}];`
FindRoot[a, {ω, 500000}]
```

Comment: Could you make your question clear carefully explaining your problem and providing the code that gives you the error?

Comment: Example using extended precision here :- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/201797/363

Comment: You have constants that differ by **dozens of orders of magnitude**, which will make numerical calculations slow and unreliable. Please, work in **natural units**, where all constants are of order 1. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you check all your equations.  You can get rid of the warnings by increasing the `WorkingPrecision` in your `FindRoot` function, but your answer will be essentially the same.  Have you looked at your value for `a`?  It is complex.  You say you get the wrong answer, but you don't say what sort of answer you expect.